# java_home environment variable in linux not found

Tags: centos, environment-variables, java-7

I'm trying to add java_home in linux machine (centos 5.8)

I'm adding this part to setting JAVA_HOME and PATH for all users in my machine

> ## vi /etc/profile
>
> export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdkx.x.x_xx
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

after seting it up, i try to verify it by using echo command

> echo $JAVA_HOME

but it does not give me any path.Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been edited, answer doesn't make sense anymore.

Left as a placeholder for comments.

`echo $SHELL` will tell you which shell you are using. Most likely /bin/bash.

Assuming bash, /etc/profile is only read for a login shell (bash --login), not just a new interactive shell.

i.e. if you

```
sh1% vi /etc/profile
sh1% bash # /etc/profile not read
sh2% echo $JAVA_HOME
sh2%


sh1% vi /etc/profile
sh2% bash --login # /etc/profile should be read.
sh2% echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/blah/blah/blah
sh2%
```

Comment: sorry my mistakes.i've already put that command.but it still shows nothing.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Are you sure it is setup to read /etc/profile? I assume you start a new shell to verify the change (i.e. force /etc/profile to be read)? Is your local user shell doing anything to unset JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: i'm not so sure about that.because this is the first time i'm using linux machine.normally i'm using windows.and i can implement it without any hassle.Can you give me directions any steps that i should take?

Answer (score 2):

This method will persist OS updates

echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default/" > /etc/profile.d/java_home.sh

If you have more then on version of java install there may be trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The JAVA_HOME path is different because we often install different version JDK and maybe different places.  Once a I try to find the general way.  There is the result.

Firstly, to query the installed jdk package name: `rpm -qa|grep java`

my result is:**java-1.6.0-openjdk**

Secondly, to query the installed place of this package

```
rpm -ql java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

Most files is under: **/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/**

go there to confirm it is a real JDK directory

Thirdly, execute `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/` in terminal.  Or add it **/etc/bashrc** for all user.